# Customize frontend and backend magento2 using js without using phtml file

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs-config.js

Just to explain in simple words.
I want to use the js file in the frontend and backend of magento2 but without using the PHTML file.Just directly usage by getting field name, or id or something.